# Rails custom routes, the point of the as: symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this example, what would be the point of the `as: :logout` parameter?

```
get 'logout', to: 'devise/registrations#destroy', as: :logout
```

In my views, I can call this route by specifying logout_path. Is it the `as: :logout` parameter that's doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, you can specify how you want the path named using `as` in your routes.

You can read more about [naming routes here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-names).

The `as` parameter doesn't need to match anything in the path or action:

```
get 'get-me-outta-here', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
# note that logging out is to do with devise sessions not registrations
```